# Remove several git commits from parent branch

Tags: git, github

I pushed some commits to a `feature_branch` and integrated the latest state of the parent branch `staging`. Then, pushed other few ones.

I did not use rebase and now my `feature_branch`'s history looks like this:

```
feature_commit_Y

feature_commit_X

staging_commit_D

staging_commit_C

feature_commit_B

feature_commit_A
```

How can I get rid of those 2 staging commits so I can pull rebase and then push my future feature_commits to come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

The `-i`  option will start an interactive rebase and `HEAD~4` will include the last 4 commits for rebase. Commenting out the commits will take out the commits from the list of commits to be applied. You can then continue the rebase which will apply feature_commit_X and feature_commit_y

Comment: You should include some more information but I guess you don't feel like talking.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming both `feature_commit_X` and `feature_commit_Y` are single commits:

   ```
   git checkout feature_commit_B
   git cherry-pick feature_commit_X feature_commit_Y
   ```

   `git cherry-pick` copies a set of commits to the current branch.
2. In any case:

   ```
   git rebase --onto feature_commit_B staging_commit_D feature_commit_Y
   ```

   This will “transplant” the commits starting with the **one after** `staging_commit_D` up to `feature_commit_Y` onto `feature_commit_B`. If you use a branch name in the place of `feature_commit_Y`, this branch will be updated.